# Manejo de instancias de aplicación de consola C#

Tags: c#

Me encuentro finalizando una aplicación de consola, la cuál requiere poder correr varias instancias de la misma, pero ubicadas en diferentes directorios. Qué librería debería utilizar para manipular y/o nombrar a cada una de las instancias que se ejecuten? Por el momento la app al iniciar por 1ra vez genera un número random de 4 dígitos y los almacena en una base de datos, al volver a iniciar verifica en la base si ya tiene un número asignado y sino lo genera, se podría utilizar ese número para diferenciar las instancia a nivel Windows? Muchas gracias!

Comment: La verdad que no entiendo tu idea, si quieres que tu ejecutable se ejecute teniendo ya el ejecutable corriendo, pues vuelvele a dar doble clicks tantas veces como quieras y este se ejecutará n veces, explica más para entenderte mejor

Comment: Disculpá, no fui del todo claro, cada ejecutable tiene un ID configurable dentro de su 'exe.config', por eso tienen que estar en directorios diferentes, por ejemplo, un ejecutable en 'C:\App' con el ID '1' al iniciar levanta de la base de datos la información del cliente 'ID = 1' y el ejecutable en 'D:\App' con el ID '2' hace lo mismo pero con la información del cliente 'ID = 2'. Gracias por responder.

Comment: ¿Por qué no usas el PID del propio proceso que asigna Windows? [Referencia](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.id?view=net-5.0)

Comment: Algo de eso había visto, pero al momento de intentar correr el ejecutable desde otro directorio me arroja el error de que ya está instalado en otro directorio, voy a volver a intentar por ese lado, muchas gracias.

Comment: >Hola puedes usar algo como esto: var exists = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location)).Count() > 1;  pero debes pasar el argumento de la dirección en el binario que compiles.